# AS theme editor not showing preview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-theme

My AS version is 1.4 in stable chanel. When I'm entering theme editor, I have an empty preview screen.[image]

Still the same problem on 1.5.1, got the stack from event log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.tools.idea.configurations.ConfigurationMenuAction$PreviewAction.actionPerformed(ConfigurationMenuAction.java:269)
at com.intellij.ui.popup.PopupFactoryImpl$ActionPopupStep$1.run(PopupFactoryImpl.java:746)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:734)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:569)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:382)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about an error in an archaic version of Android Studio and should probably have been a bug report instead.